# profiling golang runtime.systemstack

Tags: go, profiler

I have a networking app written in go. the business logic isn't important.
The problem is I'm struggling to utilize the full capabilites of my machine
and when I profile the applicaiton most of the time is spent in runtime stuff. 
It seems that ALOT of time is spent under `runtime.systemstack`
I don't understand what it means or how to increase performance.
I add the profiling of the related slow execution methods.
[svg file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByQSPd8fhPlzTGZ0V09pc2RvaUU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: which go version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

If you did cpu profiling (`go test -cpuprofile`), [issue 10609](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10609) mentioned "runtime: cpu profile is not useful due to systemstack" ([fixed here](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/9506), for [Go 1.5](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/db6f88a84b126877bd523df8c45af06779ce0e42))

You can have a more interesting view with the recent Go 1.10 trace: see "[Using Go 1.10 new trace features to debug an integration test](https://medium.com/@cep21/using-go-1-10-new-trace-features-to-debug-an-integration-test-1dc39e4e812d)"

```
go test -trace trace.out
go tool trace -http=localhost:8080 trace.out
```

See an [example here](https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2017/go-execution-tracer/).
You will see clearly the inactivity period for each of your processors.